# How to show pie, bar chart in pdf using dompdf

Tags: bar-chart, pie-chart, dompdf

Hi I am using [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

I have report page where i have used [google pie chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) and [google bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart). The charts work fine in the browser. I have to display that these chart in pdf file that is  created with DOMPDF. I used the same code withing the code that generates the pdf but it did not work. Is it possible to create pdf file with the google bar and pie chart? If yes, how can i implement and if not then is there any other way to create the pdf with pie chart?

Hope to get answer soon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

dompdf does not currently support client-generated content (i.e. something generated using JavaScript). The Google visualization library you're pointing to is dynamically generated in the client.

If you want to use a dynamically-generated chart in dompdf you'll have to use something that generates it on the server. Google does have something like this in it's [image charts library](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/), but [it's been deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) (i.e. currently, guaranteed availability is only [until 2015](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms)). You can find similar libraries.

If you still want to use client-generated charts you can try a product like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It's based on the webkit rendering engine and supports client-side scripting.